# how to structure django templates with django restframework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a Django project that currently has the following structures:

[image: project structure]

And each sub-packges (marketdata / oms / portfolio / rebalance) are all django apps that just provide Restful APIs, and they all get mapped in the "app\url.py" like this:
[image]

I am trying to build the front-end of the project using Django template engine. Where do you think I should put my template files to? Should I create a new app within this project called "front-end" and put them all there? or should I put them under the most relevant existing apps (for example, login.html goes into "user" app)

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Make a 'templates' folder under 'oms-api/app/' and in your settings paste the below code

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```